# Can I install an HDD in a MacBook Pro 13" 2015

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, hdd

Is it possible to install my old MacBook Pro HDD into the latest 2015 model?
My understanding is that the 2015 model uses PCIe Flash Storage. Perhaps there is a slot for an HDD...

Alternatively, can I run the machine off my old HDD externally?

Comment: There's barely room to put a business card in there, let alone an HD - see https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Retina+Display+Mid+2014+SSD+Replacement/27694 Why would you want to boot a new, SSD-equipped machine from an old, slow HD, on an even slower external bus anyway? As it stands, this is sounding very much like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: I urgently need to access my files and my current machine is broken. Can you suggest anything else?

Comment: You can put the old drive in a USB enclosure & just mount it as an external drive. Without a working older machine or a Time Machine backup you cannot migrate to the new one, so you'd have to copy any important data manually. The new machine will not be able to boot from the old machine's boot drive anyway.